# WCF: Tasks on startup

Tags: wcf

I am developing a WCF service, hosted in IIS 7. Now I want to do the following:

- Refresh some static varaibles (caches) whenever the appliacation pool is recycled or restarted.
- Do some basic validation checks after deployment. My idea to do it when the *.svc page is displayed in the browser.

Are there ways to hook up the application pool startup and the display of the *.svc page?

Answer (score 4):

You could implement your own ServiceHostFactory, allowing you to perform a variety of actions during the creation of the ServiceHost.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702697.aspx